# Discord.js Send a message every X seconds with Client.on('ready', () => { });

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to send a message every X seconds and that the user who reacts first gives him 10 coins.

The problem does not come from the system of coins, it is correctly executed.

This code does not work and tells me
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')`

I know this is because I'm not using `Client.on('message', message => {  })` but I really wish it would go through `ready` is there any way to do it differently? Can you help me to correct this code?

```js
Client.on('ready', () => {
    const fs = require('fs');

    const userCoin = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Storage/userCoin.json', 'utf-8'));

    const channel2up22 = Client.channels.cache.get('935549530210983976');

                    //Random Drop
    const doSomething = () => {
        let Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Wild Gift  ! | GuinGame - v2.0 ")
                    .setColor('#caabd0')
                    .setDescription("Be the **first** to react ``''`` to this message to win **10 !**")
                    .setThumbnail("https://media.giphy.com/media/Jv1Xu8EBCOynpoGBwd/giphy.gif")
                    .setFooter(text=" GuinbearBot  |   Guinbeargang.io")
                    .setTimestamp()
                    channel2up22.send(Embed)
                    .then(message => {
                        message.react('');
                    Client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
                        if (reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id == "338621907161317387") {
                            message.delete();
                            var Magic09 = 1;
                            while (Magic09 <= 10)
                                {
                                userCoin[user.id].CoinsAmount++;
                                Magic09++;
                                }
                        fs.writeFile('Storage/userCoin.json', JSON.stringify(userCoin), (err) => {if (err) console.error(err);})
                            let Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle("Wild Gift  ! | GuinGame - v2.0 ")
                            .setColor('#caabd0')
                            .setDescription("<@"+ user.id + "> has won the **Wild Gift  !**")
                            .setThumbnail("https://media.giphy.com/media/Jv1Xu8EBCOynpoGBwd/giphy.gif")
                            .setFooter(text=" GuinbearBot  |   Guinbeargang.io")
                            .setTimestamp()
                            channel2up22.send(Embed)
                        }
                    })
                    }).catch(console.error);
      }
    setInterval(doSomething(), 5000)
  })

                    //Random Drop
        });
```

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/ This site should be able to give you the basics of everything to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to fully test this code but this should work assuming all this code goes into a single file, if you get errors or anything comment below and I'll see what I can do to help out.

```js
// Near top of file but after you have defined your client with const Client = new Discord.Client()
const fs = require('fs')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new Discord.Client ({
    intents: /*your intents here*/,
})
const guild = Client.guilds.cache.get('935549530210983976')
const channel2up22 = guild.channels.cache.get('935549530210983976');
// channels are an element of the guild not the client
const userCoin = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Storage/userCoin.json', 'utf-8'));

// placing the function outside of a listener and can be called at anytime
function doSomething() {
    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Wild Gift  ! | GuinGame - v2.0 ")
        .setColor('#caabd0')
        .setDescription("Be the **first** to react ``''`` to this message to win **10 !**")
        .setThumbnail("https://media.giphy.com/media/Jv1Xu8EBCOynpoGBwd/giphy.gif")
        .setFooter({
            text: " GuinbearBot  |   Guinbeargang.io"
        })
        .setTimestamp()
    channel2up22.send({
        embeds: [Embed]
    }).then(message => {
        message.react('');
    }).catch(console.error);
}

Client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(doSomething(), 5000)
    // every 5 seconds
})

// you want to avoid nesting listeners if at all possible
Client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel2up22) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === "338621907161317387") {
            // only lets one user react
            reaction.message.delete();
            var Magic09 = 1;
            while (Magic09 <= 10) {
                userCoin[user.id].CoinsAmount;
                Magic09++;
            }
            fs.writeFile('Storage/userCoin.json', JSON.stringify(userCoin), (err) => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
            })
            const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Wild Gift  ! | GuinGame - v2.0 ")
                .setColor('#caabd0')
                .setDescription(`${user} has won the **Wild Gift  !**`)
                .setThumbnail("https://media.giphy.com/media/Jv1Xu8EBCOynpoGBwd/giphy.gif")
                .setFooter({
                    text: " GuinbearBot  |   Guinbeargang.io"
                })
                .setTimestamp()
            channel2up22.send({
                embeds: [Embed]
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your first help !!

I get an error back :

``Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')``

On line ``const channel2up22 = guild.channels.cache.get('935549530210983976');``

Comment: Did you change 'guildID' to an actual guild Id

Comment: Just saw an error that I made and I updated the code `if (reaction.channel.id === channel2up22) {` should now be `if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel2up22) {`

Comment: I also updated it on my side, and yes don't worry I took into account your indentations and replace ``'guildID'`` by the id of my discord server (it is ``'935549530210983976'``), unfortunately, I still have the error

Comment: Do me a favor and add these two lines under the "ready" listener, and then post the result and an edit to your question: `console.log(Client)` and `console.log(guild)`

Comment: I don't really need all the code, but do if they error

Comment: ``console.log(Client);`` give me ``Client {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, _timeouts: Set(1), _intervals: Set(2), …}`` and
    ``console.log(guild);`` give me ``undefined``

Comment: Ok so then can you show me where in your code you have the `const guild` line, it should be outside of a listener and below the line that defines your client, I'll update my code to show where

Comment: Just making sure, this is all being done in your main bot.js file right?

Comment: I redid another answerin this thread where I show you my code from A to Z, I hope that's what you asked me to do, if not, excuse me.

Comment: No but I believe that you need to do a it more research on code writing because I can’t help much more without seeing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code after your first modifications,

I got now an error back : `Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels') on the line : const channel2up22 = guild.channels.cache.get('935549530210983976');`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client;
const fs = require('fs')
const guild = Client.guilds.cache.get('925830522138148976');

const channel2up22 = 
 guild.channels.cache.get('935549530210983976');

const userCoin = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Storage/userCoin.json', 'utf-8'));

function doSomething() {
    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Wild Gift  ! | GuinGame - v2.0 ")
        .setColor('#caabd0')
        .setDescription("Be the **first** to react ``''`` to this message to win **10 !**")
        .setThumbnail("https://media.giphy.com/media/Jv1Xu8EBCOynpoGBwd/giphy.gif")
        .setFooter({
            text: " GuinbearBot  |   Guinbeargang.io"
        })
        .setTimestamp()
    channel2up22.send({
        embeds: [Embed]
    }).then(message => {
        message.react('');
    }).catch(console.error);
}

Client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(doSomething(), 5000)
});


Client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel2up22) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === "338621907161317387") {
            reaction.message.delete();
            var Magic09 = 1;
            while (Magic09 <= 10) {
                userCoin[user.id].CoinsAmount;
                Magic09++;
            }
            fs.writeFile('Storage/userCoin.json', JSON.stringify(userCoin), (err) => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
            })
            const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Wild Gift  ! | GuinGame - v2.0 ")
                .setColor('#caabd0')
                .setDescription(`${user} has won the **Wild Gift  !**`)
                .setThumbnail("https://media.giphy.com/media/Jv1Xu8EBCOynpoGBwd/giphy.gif")
                .setFooter({
                    text: " GuinbearBot  |   Guinbeargang.io"
                })
                .setTimestamp()
            channel2up22.send({
                embeds: [Embed]
            })
        }
    }
});
```